# 'An entry has been added to the Windows event log of the server.' error upon InfoPath submission

Tags: error, form

I've build a simple form in InfoPath 2007 with 'Submit' button using Custom Data Connection to send form data via Email. When I preview form in InfoPath form is sent correctly to email box, however once Published to SharePoint and embedded on website as Web Part, same form returns below error upon submission.

Please advice.

### **error:**

An error occurred while using the form. For more information, contact the site administrator.

An entry has been added to the Windows event log of the server.
Log ID:5567

Correlation ID:1529c69a-32ec-407d-84bc-02b86a19cc5e

Comment: Need a bit more than that. Could you please get the corresponding entries in the ULS which matches the Correlation ID you get there?

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you running?

Comment: Hi Rounn, that was version SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score -2):

This issue was caused by the fact that SMTP service wasn't set up correctly.

Comment: Please can you add more detail to help users who may encounter the same problem. Thanks.